# image of eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $X$ and $t$ be an eigenvalue. Let $K$ be the eigenspace of $t$ i.e. 
$K=\ker(T-tI)$. I am interseted in $T(K)$. One way I reason that $T(K)=\lbrace T(x):x\in K\rbrace=\lbrace tx:x\in K\rbrace$. But another way:
$T(K)=\lbrace T(x):x\in K\rbrace=\lbrace T(x):T(x)=tx\rbrace=\lbrace tx: x\in X\rbrace$ So which is correct?

Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct.

In the second the last equality is false -- it is not true that for all $x \in X$: $T(x) = tx$. It only holds for $x \in K$.